# Does the addition of two matrices yield the the addition of the corresponding eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume  $Z,B \in C^{2 \times 2}$ and that $c \in C$ is an eigenvalue of $Z$ and $u \in C$ is an eigenvalue of $B$. Then $c+u$ is an eigenvalue of $Z+B$.

Is this statement true or false?

It seems to be false, since the eigenvalues are determined by solving the characteristic equation.

Comment: Try some random matrices.

Comment: clearly false as you actually eliminate entire eigenvalues. It is impossible to determine the eigenvalues for Z+B from Z and B

In short, adding matrices together will seriously change the geometry of their corresponding linear map's linear subspaces.

Comment: Let $Z$ be the matrix with $1$ in the upper-left corner and zero elsewhere and $B$ the matrix with $1$ in the lower right corner and zero elsewhere. What so you observe?

Comment: This is almost ever false.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Z=diag(1,-1)$ and $B=diag(0,1)$, it is possible to form $4$ distinct sums but $Z+B$ only have two eigenvalues.

Hence the statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if the two matrices were diagonal in respect with the same basis. Then the matrix which is the addition of these two matrices will have its Eigen values as the addition of the two earlier matrices.

Comment: It's true that all the EV of the new matrix are sums of EVs of the old ones, but not each sum is necessarily an EV. See the other answer.